# replace an element in list with its first occurence but keep replacing for all occurences- Prolog

Tags: list, replace, prolog

I have just started programing in Prolog, using tkeclipse. What I want to do, is to replace an element of the list with another element on the first place that it occurs. However, when I press the more button (;) I want the query to return also the other solutions. Example:

```
?- replace(1,a,[1,2,3],R).

R = [a, 2, 3]
Yes
?- replace(1,a,[1,2,1,1,3],R).
R = [a, 2, 1, 1, 3] ;
R = [1, 2, a, 1, 3] ;
R = [1, 2, 1, a, 3] ;
No
```

What I wrote so far, works fine, but in the end, after [1,2,1,a,3], I also get [1,2,1,1,3] instead of no. My code is as follows:

```
%%% replace/4

replace(_,_,[],[]).
replace(X,Y,[X|T],[Y|T]).


replace(X,Y,[H|T],[H|T2]) :-  
    replace(X,Y,T,T2).
```

Answer (score 1):

Just **delete** the first clause

```
replace(_,_,[],[]).
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You `[1,2,1,1,3]` because:

`replace(1,a,[1,2,1,1,3],[1,2,1,1,3])` is successful by

- always taking the third clause, reducing the pre-replacement-list and the result-of-the-replacement list element by element
- succeeding on the empty list by taking the first clause

You want:

1. Success on the empty list (0 replacements); and also
2. A stream of of exactly-one-replacements

And so:

```
replace(_,_,[],[]) :- !. % make this deterministic with a a cut

replace(X,Y,PreList,PostList) :-
   replace_2(X,Y,PreList,PostList).

% replace_2/4 is the same as replace/4 but does NOT succeed for the empty list

replace_2(X,Y,[X|T],[Y|T]).

replace_2(X,Y,[H|T],[H|T2]) :-  
    replace_2(X,Y,T,T2).
```

And so:

```
?- replace(1,a,[1,2,3],R).
R = [a, 2, 3] ;
false.

?- replace(1,a,[1,2,1,1,3],R).
R = [a, 2, 1, 1, 3] ;
R = [1, 2, a, 1, 3] ;
R = [1, 2, 1, a, 3] ;
false.

?- replace(foo,a,[1,2,1,1,3],R).
false.

?- replace(foo,a,[],R).
R = [] ;
false.
```

Comment: Why would you want  `replace(foo,a,[],[])` to succeed? No replacement was made ;-) `replace(1, a, [2,3,4], R)` suceeds neither.

Comment: @tiffi I dunno! I'm just following orders!

Comment: Are you having a private conversation? I cannot find such orders.

Comment: @tiffi "What I wrote so far, works fine, but..." is relatively clear.

Comment: I interpret this as "works fine with regard to the first example and also until a certain point with regar to the second example" - I see nothing indicating that he wants empty lists to have a special treatment.

Comment: `I'm just following orders!` OK, please send me lots of money. :)